# Canont able to Edit the Header image in Hestia Theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When i change the header image in the hestia theme , it is not appearing in the webpage, it is not reflecting . please guide me how to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the header image on internal pages/posts, you need to select a featured image for that page/post https://prnt.sc/pyy540 and it will appear like this https://prnt.sc/pyy5c3.
For pages that don't have a featured image option ( like archive page for example ) you can add a header image in Appearance > Customize > Header Options > Header Settings > Current Header. https://prnt.sc/pyy5vy If you want that image to override the individual header images, you can also check the Enable Header Image Sitewide check.
If you want to change the header image on the homepage, that can be changed from Appearance > Customize > Frontpage sections > Big title section > Image https://prnt.sc/pyy65r